# How to run Spark code in Airflow?

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

Hello people of the Earth!
I'm using Airflow to schedule and run Spark tasks.
All I found by this time is python DAGs that Airflow can manage.

 DAG example:

```
spark_count_lines.py
import logging

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator

from datetime import datetime

args = {
  'owner': 'airflow'
  , 'start_date': datetime(2016, 4, 17)
  , 'provide_context': True
}

dag = DAG(
  'spark_count_lines'
  , start_date = datetime(2016, 4, 17)
  , schedule_interval = '@hourly'
  , default_args = args
)

def run_spark(**kwargs):
  import pyspark
  sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
  df = sc.textFile('file:///opt/spark/current/examples/src/main/resources/people.txt')
  logging.info('Number of lines in people.txt = {0}'.format(df.count()))
  sc.stop()

t_main = PythonOperator(
  task_id = 'call_spark'
  , dag = dag
  , python_callable = run_spark
)
```

The problem is I'm not good in Python code and have some tasks written in Java. My question is how to run Spark Java jar in python DAG? Or maybe there is other way yo do it? I found spark submit: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

But I don't know how to connect everything together. Maybe someone used it before and has working example. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should be able to use `BashOperator`. Keeping the rest of your code as is, import required class and system packages:

```
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

import os
import sys
```

set required paths:

```
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = '/path/to/spark/root'
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'], 'bin'))
```

and add operator:

```
spark_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='spark_java',
    bash_command='spark-submit --class {{ params.class }} {{ params.jar }}',
    params={'class': 'MainClassName', 'jar': '/path/to/your.jar'},
    dag=dag
)
```

You can easily extend this to provide additional arguments using Jinja templates.

You can of course adjust this for non-Spark scenario by replacing `bash_command` with a template suitable in your case, for example:

```
bash_command = 'java -jar {{ params.jar }}'
```

and adjusting `params`.

Comment: if i am not mistaken, this means the Spark is being run on the same machine running Airflow? What about running on a separate Spark cluster?

Comment: @cryanbhu If you mean driver then the answer is positive (as long as Spark runs in a client mode). You might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51177802), although it doesn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 22):

Airflow as of version 1.8 (released today), has

- SparkSqlOperator - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_sql_operator.py ;

SparkSQLHook code - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_sql_hook.py

- SparkSubmitOperator - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py

SparkSubmitHook code - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.py

Notice that these two new Spark operators/hooks are in "contrib" branch as of 1.8 version so not (well) documented.

So you can use SparkSubmitOperator to submit your java code for Spark execution.

Comment: The SparkSQLOperator looks like it's just the thing I need - however, I can't get it to work because I don't know what the connection string should look like - is there any documentation anywhere that can help me with this?

Comment: If you don't set it - connection will default to yarn execution mode - see https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.py#L33

Comment: can we run spark2-submit using Airflow?

Comment: @DeepeshRehi yes, that's what the `spark_binary` argument is for. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d2f224992eb2f1db3e6520c45b65340d244925bd/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.py#L90

Answer (score 15):

There is an example of `SparkSubmitOperator` usage for Spark 2.3.1 on kubernetes (minikube instance):

```py
"""
Code that goes along with the Airflow located at:
http://airflow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html
"""
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'user@mail.com',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 7, 27),
    'email': ['user@mail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    'end_date': datetime(2018, 7, 29),
}

dag = DAG(
    'tutorial_spark_operator', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(1))

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

print_path_env_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_path_env',
    bash_command='echo $PATH',
    dag=dag)

spark_submit_task = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='spark_submit_job',
    conn_id='spark_default',
    java_class='com.ibm.cdopoc.DataLoaderDB2COS',
    application='local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/cppmpoc-dl-0.1.jar',
    total_executor_cores='1',
    executor_cores='1',
    executor_memory='2g',
    num_executors='2',
    name='airflowspark-DataLoaderDB2COS',
    verbose=True,
    driver_memory='1g',
    conf={
        'spark.DB_URL': 'jdbc:db2://dashdb-dal13.services.dal.bluemix.net:50001/BLUDB:sslConnection=true;',
        'spark.DB_USER': Variable.get("CEDP_DB2_WoC_User"),
        'spark.DB_PASSWORD': Variable.get("CEDP_DB2_WoC_Password"),
        'spark.DB_DRIVER': 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver',
        'spark.DB_TABLE': 'MKT_ATBTN.MERGE_STREAM_2000_REST_API',
        'spark.COS_API_KEY': Variable.get("COS_API_KEY"),
        'spark.COS_SERVICE_ID': Variable.get("COS_SERVICE_ID"),
        'spark.COS_ENDPOINT': 's3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net',
        'spark.COS_BUCKET': 'data-ingestion-poc',
        'spark.COS_OUTPUT_FILENAME': 'cedp-dummy-table-cos2',
        'spark.kubernetes.container.image': 'ctipka/spark:spark-docker',
        'spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName': 'spark'
        },
    dag=dag,
)

t1.set_upstream(print_path_env_task)
spark_submit_task.set_upstream(t1)
```

The code using variables stored in Airflow variables:
[image]

Also, you need to create a new spark connection or edit existing 'spark_default' with 
extra dictionary `{"queue":"root.default", "deploy-mode":"cluster", "spark-home":"", "spark-binary":"spark-submit", "namespace":"default"}`:
[image]

Comment: a little confused by the conf properties option in Airflow. from the above code it looks like custom key=value is getting passed to conf. how is that possible? maybe I'm not understanding this option but I thought it was meant only for spark configuration properties that are typically passed with `--conf` flag in spark-submits.

Comment: @horatio1701d the `conf` keys it is just array of `--conf` keys that we passing to spark_submit. it can be k8s, spark or just our custom keys

Comment: Strange there is no SparkSubmitHook example as this is now deprecated. I mean anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Admin` -> `Connection` -> `Create` in Airflow UI. Create a new SSH connection by providing host = IP address, port = 22  and extra as `{"key_file": "/path/to/pem/file", "no_host_key_check":true}`

This host should be the Spark cluster master from which you can submit spark-jobs. Next, you need to create a DAG with SSHOperator. Following is the template for this.

```
with DAG(dag_id='ssh-dag-id',
     schedule_interval="05 12 * * *",
     catchup=False) as dag:
     
spark_job = ("spark-submit --class fully.qualified.class.name "
             "--master yarn "
             "--deploy-mode client "
             "--driver-memory 6G "
             "--executor-memory 6G "
             "--num-executors 6 "
             "/path/to/your-spark.jar")

ssh_run_query = SSHOperator(
    task_id="random_task_id",
    ssh_conn_id="name_of_connection_you just_created",
    command=spark_job,
    get_pty=True,
    dag=dag)

ssh_run_query
```

That's it. You also get the complete logs for this Spark job in Airflow.