# Apache airflow - automation - how to run spark submit job with param

Tags: apache-spark, airflow

Am new to spark and airflow, trying to understand how I can use airflow to kick off a job along with parameters needed for the job. I use the below spark-submit command to run a specific job for specific dates in edge node as below,

```
EXECUTORS_MEM=4G
EXECUTORS_NUM=300
STARTDAY=20180401
ENDDAY=20180401
QUEUE=m
jobname=x

/home/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit --verbose --master yarn --deploy-mode client $EXECUTORS_NUM  --executor-memory $EXECUTORS_MEM --executor-cores 1 --driver-memory 8G  --queue $QUEUE --class test.core.Driver --jars $JARS2 abc.jar --config=/a/b/c/test.config --appName=abc --sparkMaster=yarnclient --job=$jobname --days=$STARTDAY,$ENDDAY
```

So can you please let me know if I create .py something similar to the code below to run the job in airflow ? 
Is this how your supposed to run a job & pass parameters ?

How do I pass parameter like I did for launching a job in edge node ?

If I automate the job to run daily I would like the start date to be "t-7", so if today's date is 4/20/2018 the start date to the job has to be 4/13/2018. How do I achieve it ?

```
###############.py file example ##############
**********************************************

    import BashOperator

    import os
    import sys

    os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = '/path/to/spark/root'
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'], 'bin'))

    import os
    import sys


    os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = '/home/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/'
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'], 'bin'))
    and add operator:

    spark_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='spark_java',
        bash_command='spark-submit --class test.core.Driver abc.jar',
        params={'EXECUTORS_MEM': '4G', 'EXECUTORS_NUM': '300', 'QUEUE' :'m' , 'jobname' : 'x'},
        dag=dag

)

################### EOF ######################
**********************************************
```

---

### New .py file - please correct me if anything is wrong

- How do I pass the params to Run a spark version which in different path ?
- Pass a jar which in different path
- Is it the right way to pass the parameters like shown below?
- Is it possible to pass certain start & end date manually for the job to run?

  ```
  from airflow import DAG

  from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator
  from airflow.utils import timezone


  DEFAULT_DATE = timezone.datetime(2017, 1, 1)

  args = {
      'owner': 'airflow',
      'start_date': DEFAULT_DATE
  }
  dag = DAG('test_dag_id', default_args=args)

  _config = {
      'config' : '/a/b/c/d/prod.config' 
      'master' : 'yarn'
      'deploy-mode' : 'client'
      'sparkMaster' : 'yarnclient'
      'class' : 'core.Driver' 
      'driver_classpath': 'parquet.jar',
      'jars': '/a/b/c/d/test.jar',
      'total_executor_cores': 4,
      'executor_cores': 1,
      'EXECUTORS_MEM': '8G',
      'EXECUTORS_NUM': 500,
      'executor-cores' : '1',
      'driver-memory' : '8G',
      'JOB_NAME' : ' ',
      'QUEUE' : ' ',
      'verbose' : ' '
      'start_date' : ' '
      'end_date' : ' '
      ]
  }

  operator = SparkSubmitOperator(
      task_id='spark_submit_job',
      dag=dag,
      **_config
  )
  ```

Comment: I added an example to my answer below.  Let me know if there's anything that is unclear!

Answer (score 7):

The start date is something you set once, and it's intended to be set absolutely, not relative to the current day.

Like this:

```
from airflow import DAG

dag = DAG(
    ...
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 13),
)
```

It's possible to set start date as a delta like `datetime.timedelta(days=7)`, but this is not recommended, since it would change the start date if you were to delete the DAG (including all references such as DAG runs, task instances, etc) and run it again from scratch on another day.  The best practice is for DAGs to be idempotent.

For submitting a job to Spark, there is a [`SparkSubmitOperator`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/f520990fe0b7a70f80bec68cb5c3f0d41e3e984d/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py#L26) that wraps the `spark-submit` shell command.  That would be the preferred option.  That said, you can do basically anything with a `BashOperator`, so that's a workable alternative too.

The linked code for SparkSubmitOperator is well documented for each argument it accepts.  You can point to your .jar file with the `application` kwarg, pass Spark config with `conf`.  There are also kwargs for passing info like executor cores and memory.  You can use `application_args` to pass a list of arbitrary args through to your Spark application.

Here's an example of using `SparkSubmitOperator` copied and slightly simplified from the unit tests for it in Airflow.  Note that it uses `**` to explode the kwargs from a dict to initialize the Spark operator, but that's just how the test is structured.  You could just as easily pass each config value as a kwarg.

```
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator
from airflow.utils import timezone


DEFAULT_DATE = timezone.datetime(2017, 1, 1)

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': DEFAULT_DATE
}
dag = DAG('test_dag_id', default_args=args)

_config = {
    'conf': {
        'parquet.compression': 'SNAPPY'
    },
    'files': 'hive-site.xml',
    'py_files': 'sample_library.py',
    'driver_classpath': 'parquet.jar',
    'jars': 'parquet.jar',
    'packages': 'com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0',
    'exclude_packages': 'org.bad.dependency:1.0.0',
    'repositories': 'http://myrepo.org',
    'total_executor_cores': 4,
    'executor_cores': 4,
    'executor_memory': '22g',
    'keytab': 'privileged_user.keytab',
    'principal': 'user/spark@airflow.org',
    'name': '{{ task_instance.task_id }}',
    'num_executors': 10,
    'verbose': True,
    'application': 'test_application.py',
    'driver_memory': '3g',
    'java_class': 'com.foo.bar.AppMain',
    'application_args': [
        '-f', 'foo',
        '--bar', 'bar',
        '--start', '{{ macros.ds_add(ds, -1)}}',
        '--end', '{{ ds }}',
        '--with-spaces', 'args should keep embdedded spaces',
    ]
}

operator = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='spark_submit_job',
    dag=dag,
    **_config
)
```

Source: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/f520990fe0b7a70f80bec68cb5c3f0d41e3e984d/tests/contrib/operators/test_spark_submit_operator.py

Comment: I was able to build a structure similar to you, but I don't understand the part where the .py file kicks of a spark submit command using SparkSubmitOperator. From you example I see we can pass the params through _config ,  but how do I run a spark submit that's in a specific path say /home/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/ or it only runs the spark that's only installed on the edge node you have airflow on - how is SparkSubmitOperator kicking of a spark submit ?

I added my .py file close to the sprak submit command I use, please help me correct the script if there is anything wrong?

Comment: The spark home path should be specified in airflow as an extra parameter of a spark connection (you can use the default one [as showed by @CTiPKA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51557906/6450431) ) : `{"queue":"default", "deploy-mode":"cluster", "spark-home":"", "spark-binary":"spark-submit", "namespace":"default"}`. SparkSubmitOperator just run the spark-submit command using the connection id you gave it to as the spark master (see [SparkSubmitHook](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.py) ). py_files are used only when using PySpark.