# Airflow stops following Spark job submitted over SSH

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, airflow

I'm using Apache Airflow standalone to submit my Spark jobs with [`SSHExecutorOperator`](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/ssh_execute_operator.html) to connect to the edge node and submit jobs with a simple `BashCommand`.

It's mostly working well but sometimes some random tasks are running undefinitly.

My job succeeds, but is still running according to Airflow.

When I check the logs, it's like Airflow has stopped following the job as if it didn't get the return value.

Why could this happen? Some jobs run for 10h+ and Airflow watches them successfully, while others fail.

I have only Spark's logs (at `INFO` level) without anything printed by the job driver.

It doesn't depend on the deploy mode. I used both `client` and `cluster` and it doesn't seem to depend on that. Sometimes, Airflow fails to watch some simple Python script.

To solve this issue, I was wondering if installing [this plugin](https://github.com/rssanders3/airflow-spark-operator-plugin) could work.

**EDIT :**

I'm using Airflow 1.8.

I didnt install SparkSubmitOperator because :
"The executors need to have access to the spark-submit command on the local commandline shell. Spark libraries will need to be installed.".

My airflow is just a VM with no hadoop binaries. Airflow do some SSH connection then submit on Edge node.

When I look SparkSubmitOperator documentation, I don't think I can connect to edge node to submit. There is no "conn_id" or SSH parameter.

PS2 : This morning, a job was running all night long (even if he supposed to run in 30min ... ). I use netstat to check if there my airflow application user connect with SSH and ... nothing, SSH connection died imo.

Same task, same DAG, different RUN :

*OK :*

> [2018-07-05 10:48:55,509] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-05 10:48:55,509] {ssh_execute_operator.py:146} INFO - 18/07/05 10:48:55 INFO datasources.FileFormatWriter: Job null committed.
>   [2018-07-05 10:48:55,510] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-05 10:48:55,510] {ssh_execute_operator.py:146} INFO - 18/07/05 10:48:55 INFO datasources.FileFormatWriter: Finished processing stats for job null.
>   [2018-07-05 10:49:08,407] {jobs.py:2083} INFO - Task exited with return code 0

*FAIL :*

> [2018-07-04 18:52:12,849] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-04 18:52:12,849] {ssh_execute_operator.py:146} INFO - 18/07/04 18:52:12 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 5 finished: json at CleaningTweets.scala:249, took 8.411721 s
>   [2018-07-04 18:52:13,530] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-04 18:52:13,530] {ssh_execute_operator.py:146} INFO - 18/07/04 18:52:13 INFO datasources.FileFormatWriter: Job null committed.
>   [2018-07-04 18:52:13,531] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-04 18:52:13,530] {ssh_execute_operator.py:146} INFO - 18/07/04 18:52:13 INFO datasources.FileFormatWriter: Finished processing stats for job null.

Miss return ...

LAST EDIT : I removed everylogs (print/show) of every jobs, and it seems working.

Comment: Could lost connection or ssh timeout be the problem?

Comment: It could, and I have no idea how I can check that. Was thinking about some buffer too small or some missing Airflow configuration...

Sometime, it's a specific task that stay in 'running' state all day, even if I restarted scheduler. And with no explication, he switch to 'SUCCES' after X times.

Comment: Just an idea - I haven't checked it. You could connect to the edge node and use `netstat` (or [some other tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92560)) to check active connections to see if session is still connected and if not, check sshd log for the close event. This could narrow things down...

Comment: What version of airlfow are you running? why not use the [SparkSubmitOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py) that comes with airflow, might be worth looking into at least.