# Scheduling Spark for Nightly run batch - Run Every Night Like an ETL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark job which reads a source table, does a number of map / flatten / **DATAFRAME** operations and then stores the results into a separate table FROM **TEMP TABLE** we use for reporting. Currently this job is run manually using the spark-submit script. I want to schedule it to run every night.

```
is there any way to schedule spark job for batch processing similarly like an nightly batch ETL
```

Comment: you can use Cron JOBS to schedule the script.

Comment: @dassum: any other alternative than Cron JOBS. I never used before

Comment: you can try https://azkaban.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism in Spark that will help. A cron job seems reasonable. Other options are

1. https://azkaban.github.io/
2. https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_spark-component-guide/content/ch_oozie-spark-action.html

Answer (score 0):

If you know python you can check **Airflow**.
Airflow allows one to regularly schedule a task like cron, but is additionally more flexible in allowing for certain tasks to depend on each other and makes it easy to define complex relations even in a large distributed environment.
You can check below link

[How to run Spark code in Airflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827804/how-to-run-spark-code-in-airflow)